# Stuffy, blocked nose blocked sinuses

Tags: single-word-requests

What’s the adjective beginning with ‘c’ that describes someone who has a snotty nose and mucus filling their sinuses.

Probably synonymous with “stuffy”.

> I would be feeling much better if I wasn’t so _______

I think it sounds something like congealed.

Comment: _clogged up_ may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @tmgr no don’t think so

Comment: Well, it works in the context and is idiomatic! By the way, you should _probably_ edit your question to show what research you've done to answer your own question, say which words or phrases you've rejected (and why) and possibly expand your examples section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for **congested**.  From https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/congested --

> congested
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 (of a road or place) so crowded with traffic or
>   people as to hinder or prevent freedom of movement.
>
> ‘the congested streets of the West End’ ‘the streets are often heavily
>   congested with traffic’
>
> 2 (of a part of
>   the body) abnormally full of blood.  ‘congested arteries’
>
> 2.1 (of the respiratory tract) blocked with mucus so as to hinder breathing. ‘his nose was congested’

You'll hear the word used e.g. in TV commercials for cold medicines because (I gather) it's more polite and subtle than the alternatives.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Oh I remembered:

Congested

> an unnatural accumulation of blood or other fluid in (a body part or blood vessel)
>   *the cold congested in her sinuses*

Comment: I was just getting ready to post it!

Comment: @JDM-GBG go for it, then the question will have an accepted answer faster

Comment: If your block quote is a definition you've just made up, then this answer doesn't meet our site's standards. On the other hand, if the block quote is from a dictionary and you haven't cited the source, it's plagiarism which is against our site's rules. I recommend you [edit] your answer to provide the appropriate citation and hyperlink.